# Memory leak in class Constructor of c++

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have the following class

```
class CSample
{
   char* m_pChar;
   double* m_pDouble;

 CSample():m_pChar(new char[1000]), m_pDouble(new Double[1000000])
{
}
~CSample()
{
   if(m_pChar != NULL) delete [] m_pchar;
   if(m_pDouble != NULL) delete [] m_pDouble;
}
};
```

and in my main() function i'm trying to create object of CSample

```
int main()
{
    try
  {
    CSample objSample;
  }

catch(std::bad_alloc)
{
  cout<<"Exception is caught !!! Failed to create object";
}

}
```

Say while allocating the memory for m_pDouble in constructor's initializer list, it throws the exception because of insufficient available memory. But for m_pChar it is already allocated. Since object itself is not created, the destructor wouldnt be called. Then there will be memory leak for m_pChar.

How do you avoid this memory leak ?

Comment: @jxh Actually, no. `std::default_delete` has a specialization for `T[]` that does the right thing.

Comment: In general, either a class manages *one* resource, or it has business related methods. Trying to do both at once is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @T.C.: On ideone, I have to pass the specialization in to make `unique_ptr` work with an array allocation.

Comment: @jxh Well, you do need `std::unique_ptr<char []>`, but you shouldn't have to pass `default_delete<char []>` explicitly...

Comment: @T.C.: Wouldn't that let `unique_ptr` store a `char (*)[]`?

Comment: @jxh No, it's specialized for that case as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily avoid this kind of problem by using a `vector` instead.

```
class CSample
{
   std::vector<char> m_pChar;
   std::vector<double> m_pDouble;

   CSample():m_pChar(1000), m_pDouble(1000000)
   {
   }
};
```

Generally speaking, you should aim to write classes that do not require a destructor. This makes them trivially obey the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722/315052).

Comment: Effectively making it obey the [Rule of Zero](http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/08/15/rule-of-zero.html).

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do this safely:

- Delegate memory management to another class, such as `std::unique_ptr` (C++11) or `std::vector`:

  ```
  class CSample
  {
     std::unique_ptr<char []> m_pChar;
     std::unique_ptr<double []> m_pDouble;

     CSample():m_pChar(new char[1000]), m_pDouble(new double[1000000])
     {
     }
  };
  ```

  The language guarantees that any class member already constructed will be destroyed if an exception is thrown, which will release the allocated memory.
- Perform memory allocation in the constructor body instead, and use a local try block:

  ```
  class CSample
  {
     char* m_pChar;
     double* m_pDouble;

      CSample() : m_pChar(nullptr), m_pDouble(nullptr)
      {    
          try {
              m_pChar = new char[1000];
              m_pDouble = new double[1000000];
          }
          catch(...){
              if(m_pChar) delete [] m_pChar;
              if(m_pDouble) delete [] m_pDouble;
              throw;
          }    
      }
      CSample(const CSample &other) { /* perform deep copy */ }
      CSample &operator=(const CSample &other) { /* perform deep copy of other and release my resources */ }        
      ~CSample()
      {
         if(m_pChar) delete [] m_pchar;
         if(m_pDouble) delete [] m_pDouble;
      }

  };
  ```
- Use a C++11 delegating constructor. The object is deemed constructed when the target (non-delegating) constructor completes execution, so if the delegating constructor later throws, the destructor will be called.

  ```
  class CSample
  {
      char* m_pChar;
      double* m_pDouble;

      CSample(int) : m_pChar(nullptr), m_pDouble(nullptr) { }
      CSample() : CSample(0)
      {    
          m_pChar = new char[1000];
          m_pDouble = new double[1000000];
      }
      CSample(const CSample &other) { /* perform deep copy */ }
      CSample &operator=(const CSample &other) { /* perform deep copy of other and release my resources */ }
      ~CSample()
      {
         if(m_pChar) delete [] m_pchar;
         if(m_pDouble) delete [] m_pDouble;
      }

  };
  ```

If you do not delegate resource management to another class, you would also need to [supply proper copy constructors and copy assignment operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three), as the default ones (memberwise copy/assignment) have the wrong semantics. It should be obvious that the first way is both the simplest by far and the least error prone.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why you'd rather do this than the other answer which uses a standard container?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum To illustrate how hard it is to do it right without using a `vector` or `unique_ptr`?

Comment: If you're going to describe how to do it the hard way, then at least mention the [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722) - the examples posted here are deathtraps.